# Baking problems

Tags: normals, texture-baking, normal-map

When baking a new object, the old image with saved baking disappears and a new image appears. At the same time the same image is selected, the normal node is selected and the image is saved. what could be the problem?

photo before
[image]
right after
[image]

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: it looks like you've collapsed your previous bake with the new one

Comment: @moonboots That's right, except I don't understand how. Because the image is selected correctly and the normal map is connected

Comment: The normal map *shouldn't* be connected.  What you've done is, first, bake a normal map, active to selected; then, measured the difference between normals derived from that normal map-- since it was connected-- and your selected object's normals, which happens to be zilch.  Because one is a bake of the other.